# Rails get header response for a remote image

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, http-headers, http-status-code-404

I load in my app some Facebook image of users (and for performance I load the url of this picture on the DB). But when the user change the profile pic the url must be changed too.

How can I detect the response of an external server (e.g. when is 404) so I know that I must refresh the url pictures of this user?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [rest-client](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client), execute a **head** request to the url and check the response status.